# My rendered partial '_form' appears, but is not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

Ruby 2.1.5 on Rails 4.2.0:

I have two directories. One directory is a rails-generate scaffold named 'inqueries'. The other directory is named 'welcome', which only houses a landing paged named index.html.erb. The inquery form works & submits fine as long as I'm using the view from the actual 'inquery' scaffold/directory.

I am able to render the inquery _form on my index.html.erb landing page using :

```
 <%= render partial: "inqueries/form", locals: {inquery: @Inquery} %>
```

However, this JUST renders the form. When I hit the submit button, no errors, flash messages, or inquery is submitted. It is complete non-action, including on my rails terminal.

How can I properly make the form work on my landing page?

Here is my welcome_controller.rb file. This controller handles the landing page where I am trying to render the inquery scaffold's form:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @inquery = Inquery.new
        render layout: false
      end
    end
```

This is my new rails scaffold-generated method in the inqueries_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @inquery = Inquery.new
    respond_with(@inquery)
  end
```

Sorry, Here is the Inquery _form itself:

```
<%= form_for(@inquery) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <%= f.label t('.name') %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
          <%= f.label t('.email') %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
          <%= f.label t('.phone') %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <%= f.label t('.message') %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :message, rows: 8, class: "form-control"%>
        </div>
            <%= f.submit t('.submit'), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT 2: I saw there were a couple of suggestions with the logic. I have simplified the partial just to see if I could get it to work and it still does not submit properly outside of its directory. I am new to rails, do I need to render a new action in the second directory that I am calling it into?

Comment: Could you please post the contents of the form partial?

Comment: It'd be nice if you amend your question to include the form code.

Comment: Your indentation seems to be messed up a bit, but from the looks of it, you've got a form within a form. Any reason for that?

Comment: The second `<form>` has no `action`, so it's incapable of doing anything.

Comment: I have simplified the partial and I still do not get any type of action from the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Your partial has 2 forms. The one which submits to inqueries#create is an empty form with no submit button, the other which has no action contains the text fields and the submit action.

The form_for tag will create the html  tags, you dont need to specify them again.

Tip - Switch to [haml](http://haml.info/). You won't ever look back at erb :)

This should work (not tested) -

```
<%= form_for(@inquery) do |f| %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <% if @inquery.errors.any? %>
            <h2>
                <%= pluralize(@inquery.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this inquery from being saved:
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <% @inquery.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <%= f.label t('.name') %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
          <%= f.label t('.email') %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
          <%= f.label t('.phone') %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <%= f.label t('.message') %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :message, rows: 8, class: "form-control"%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
            <%= f.submit t('.submit'), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Removing that 'end' brings up an error:  syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: The <% end %> for the iteration over @inquery.error_messages is misplaced (as it was in the question) - another good reason to switch to haml

Comment: Updated the code snippet to add an <% end %> for those pesky full_messages

Comment: I've played with the code quite a bit, including trying to pull the error messages out as well. However, no matter what change I make to that partial regarding the 'ends' I still can't get the button to submit. There is still no action happening in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Foolish error,
My welcome page is a bootstrap theme that I hadn't fully gone over. I had imported some unnecessary javascript files that I think were blocking the form.